Angular mat table with dynamic multi header row
I want to create following table with help of angular mat table.
It consists of 2 header rows with dynamic values.
Example on mat-table -
Here, its top row static - https://v15.material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-multiple-header-footer
Here Both row header has some content-
https://v15.material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-complex-flex
My top row has offset and dynamic values and second header row has repeated values like cities


you can use the exact solution from this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-multiple-header-rows?file=main.ts

this example have static 1st row in header i.e. it show static First group and second group. In my scenario i need dynamic values like dates.
